# How to duplicate circles increasing their size in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to copy a circle and re-size it at the same time, then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> several times to imitate the behavior and end up having circles with increasing diameter.

I don't want it to scale the new circle by the same fixed %, ending up with a sort of logarithmic growth related to the original circle. What I'd need to do is to have a **linear growth**, so that the increasing in the radius is linear.

Not sure if I explained it correctly, any doubt let me know!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Polar Grid Tool Method

---

### :: Quick and dirty ::

- On the Tools Palette, click and hold on the "Line Tool".
- Choose "Polar Grid Tool" from the drop-down
- Begin dragging your shape, but don't release the mouse button
- Pressing the arrow keys in this "unreleased shape" state will alter the number of line dividers, and will yield something like the result you seem to be asking for.

If that won't suffice, you either want the Scaling Tool or Blending.

## Scaling Tool Method

---

### :: An overlooked fundamental ::

Select you shape with the Selection Tool, then choose the Scale Tool (keyboard shortcut: 's').

[image: 'Select' your shape]

In this instance, you'll want to press "Enter" with the shape selected to bring up the Scale Tool Dialog, tweak the settings, and choose "Copy" at the bottom of the dialog.

[image: Tweak the dialog. Remember to "Copy"]
[image: Result Example. Mind the tick box "Scale Strokes and Effects"]

Press Cmd / Ctrl + D to repeat the effect the desired number of times. 
[image: Cmd / Ctrl + D to repeat the action]

One setting to pay attention to in the dialog is "Scale Strokes and Effects".

[image: Choose according to your design]

As you can see, the strokes in this example are not increased as in the other result:

[image: Increased width and height without increased strokes / effects]

## Blending Method

---

### :: Powerful but sometimes more than necessary ::

1. Make one circle sized as your innermost circle, and one as your outermost.
2. Select both objects.
3. In File Menu / Menu Bar: Object > Blend > Make
4. This probably won't yield the desired results, so again from your Menu options, choose Object > Blend > Blending Options*
5. In the dialog, for "Spacing", choose either "Specified Steps" or "Specified Distance". Tweak the numbers until you a result you like (make sure you have the "Preview" box ticked!)

**Alternatively, you can double-click on your "Blend Tool" in the Tools Palette to bring up your Blend Options dialog box.*

Answer (score 13):

### Option 1:

Draw 1 circle.

Select it.

Choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` from the menu.

Enter the scale amount you want in the upper fields.

Enter the number of copies you want in the `Copies` field.

Tick the `Preview`box.

[image]

When satisfied, hit <kbd>OK</kbd>

Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` to expand the effect into actual circles you can alter.

---

### Option 2:

Draw your smallest circle.

Draw your largest circle.

Select both circles and choose `Object > Blend > Make`.

Choose `Object > Blend > Blend Options` and choose `Specified steps` from the drop down menu and enter the number of circles you want (minus the 2 starting circles).

[image]

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

If you want to alter the circles, choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu.

Benefits of this method is every "step" is equally spaced.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a circle.

Select the circle and select from the menu: Object/Transform/Scale

In the pop-up window set your scaling and click OK. - Now the program remembers your transform.

1. Copy your circle. Ctrl-C
2. Paste your circle - I like Ctrl-F for paste in front.
3. Then Ctrl-D and your circle scales up.
4. Repeat as many times as you want, or optionally create an Action with these steps.

Answer (score 1):

I used the answer given by @Scott to reach the desired results.

In addition to using `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` feature. I noticed that the output is merged into one object. To split it into distinct objects, use the following solution.

1. Step 1: `Object > Expand Appearances > Expand`
2. Step 2: `Right click > Ungroup`

I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment or add a picture right now. I will add them in the future if possible. I would also appreciate if someone could add this on my behalf.